# Can for loop change value of variables explicitly in c?

Tags: c, for-loop

Why does the value of sum changes after for loop in the following code even after I have initialised it as 0 in CodeBlocks?

```
int main()
{
    int a[5], i, sum;
    sum= 0;  // value of sum is not changed after this.
    printf("\nSum=%d", sum);

    for( i=1; i<6; i++)
    {
       printf("\n\nInput %d: ", i);
       scanf("%d", &a[i]);
       printf("Sum test=%d", sum);
    }

printf("\n\nSum=%d", sum); // why does it changes?

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This code gives right result in online ide, does it have something to do with codeblocks or my computer?

Comment: array index starts with 0 so arr[5] is not allocated and the value you entered is given to sum

Comment: Indexes in C Are from zero not one. I advice a good C book first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` never changes because you never modify it.

Furthermore, you have undefined behavior because the loop index is off by one, so you make `scanf()` write beyond the end of the array `arr`, which might by coincidence be the location where `sum` is stored, this would explain why you get `Sum=4`, the value of the last input.

C arrays are `0` based: use this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

You must also include the required standard header files and test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[5], i, sum;
    sum = 0;

    printf("Sum=%d\n", sum);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\nInput %d: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            break;
        sum += a[i];
        printf("Sum test=%d\n", sum);
    }
    printf("\nSum=%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much chqrlie. The sum in my program was to be used to add the odd inputs, there is more to my program.

Comment: if ( scanf ("%d", &a[i]) != 1 )                                                                                                 {  break; }  // can you please explain this return value test.

Comment: if `scanf("%d", ...)` does not return `1`, there is no or at least invalid input pending in the input stream. `a[i]` is uninitialized, we must exit the loop to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looping over `1` to `6`! And rewrite the value of `sum` here. To avoid this, you should iterate over the scope of the array, from index `0` to `4`.

You should be aware that as the memory of `sum` is adjacent to the allocated memory of the array such a thing is happened, and it is not a rule!

Answer (score 0):

array index starts with 0 so arr[5] is not allocated and the value you entered is given to sum

if atlast you give it as input 6 then the sum value is 6